# Meteor - can't access collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've created a new collection (Areas) through the shell but for some reason when I try to publish it :

```
Meteor.publish('Areas', function(){
   return Meteor.Areas.find();
});
```

I get the following error: Exception from sub Areas id vSLHezdCrv77i6aca TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined.

I use exactly the same process for the users table and it works fine. When I query it from the mongo shell it's also okay.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Code for subscribe:

```
Template.content_profile.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
      var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
       self.subscribe('profileInfo', id);
       self.subscribe('Areas');
    });
    console.log(Areas.find().count());
  });"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to prefix it with Meteor:

```
Areas = new Mongo.Collection("areas");

Meteor.publish('Areas', function(){
   return Areas.find();
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, this worked but now I cannot manage to connect to it on the client side. I've added the code from my client.js to the original post. Would you please take a look to see if there's anything wrong with it? The console.log line ends with "ReferenceError: Areas is not defined"

Comment: You need to define Areas in a shared location (usually a folder `collections` in the root of your project).

Comment: Also, you can't subscribe to a collection directly - you need to publish the data.  Check out http://guide.meteor.com to learn about it.